# PHP Accurate Font Width

Tags: php, image, fonts, font-size

I am trying to generate a text image.

So I create a new font:

```
   $font = '../fonts/Arial.ttf';
```

Then I add some background for the text

```
   imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, ?, 12, $green);
```

And add text

```
   imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 0, 12, $white, $font, $text);
```

The problem is right now I don't know how to get the width of my font with size 12.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [ImageTTFBBox()](https://www.php.net/imagettfbbox)