# get text length in px, php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Accurate Font Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767588/php-accurate-font-width)

For example I have Arial font (22px size) text: "my name is lola" and how get this text length in pixels? (PHP languages)

Comment: What do you need this for? It is theoretically possible in GD, but the results will vary from if you output this in HTML. What do you want to do?

Comment: I need put text in right side of pictures, i must now text lenght

Comment: Then you need to read the duplicate question, if you have any queries in regards to that one, please ask within that post.

Answer (score 1):

well normaly you should be able to, make sure it has some wrapping tags like a span tag and use .width() function in jquery to get the width in pixels

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Edit: it's not php but it's the only possible way i know of doing this

Answer (score -3):

... it depends:)

so i wont get downvoted more than i already had..without getting a comment:
it depends on:

- the used font
- the OS where this font is used (the font renderer on linux is produces slightly different results that the one on windows, and probaly the same rule applies on OSX)
- wherever you are using antialising and what kind of antialising is used
- wherever the font is bold or not
- the output medium (printed fonts are not identical to displayed font because of printer characteristics)
- the letter spacing

As a solution you may use GD to render the text into a surface, and try to crop it..

Comment: That's an (unqualified) comment and not an answer.

Comment: it depends what? elaborate your answer

Comment: i get downvoted and the guy purposing a jquery solution even if the user asked a PHP solition isn't?:))

Comment: the jQuery proposal is a valid one, your's is not.

Comment: At least i gave a an answer with more then 2 words. I pointed out the fact that their are better solution using another language, most people combine php, html & javascript. Not everything is possible using one language

Comment: Quote: "A good programmer uses the best language for the given situation".

Comment: See it positive, by deleting the answer, you can earn the peer pressure badge

Comment: i wont delete it as long as i consider that i'm right...