# PHP Determining Font Size based off of width

Tags: php, fonts

I have static width of an element, and an unknown string length which is inserted by the user.  I'm trying to keep javascript out otherwise this problem would be solved via using jQuery method described in other posts.

I'm generating a static page with php that won't change and I'm trying to calculate the size of the text in order to fit inside the div.

Is this possible with only having the following:
 - String Length
 - Width of Container
 - Server side with PHP

and if so could you please lend me a hand in finding the correct solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about an HTML element, you will not be able to determine the width in PHP with 100% reliability. You would have to actually render the element in the client browser to find it out, and that is possible only using JavaScript.

Plus there are many factors on client side that can play into the result:

- The operating system's text size level
- The browser's zoom level
- The availability of the font used on the client machine

You may be best off manually determining the element's width in an average web browser with normal zoom (or if it's dynamic text, maybe use what @Jared proposes)

Comment: Thank you Pekka for outlineing that.  Good point on the Operating System + Browser zoom level (assuming is always the worst to do..)

Answer (score 1):

This answer (by Pekka, see his response as well):

[PHP Accurate Font Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767588/php-accurate-font-width)

Suggests [imagettfbbox](https://www.php.net/imagettfbbox), if you're using a truetype font.

Comment: Yup, but this is reliable only when you also use PHP's GD to actually render the content. The OP's question looks like he's trying to determine the width of a HTML element that is rendered in the client. That said, it may be a satisfactory solution anyway if 100% reliability is not required.

Comment: I'm not seeing a satisfactory way to do in PHP what the OP wants if it is about an actual HTML element, but this looks like probably a decent alternative.