# Run javascript on php HTML variable during runtime

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, httprequest

**Rewrote the entire question because evidently it was too vague**

I have HTML, this HTML needs to be processed by Javascript before I send it through E-mail.

In other words, I need to run Javascript on HTML during PHP runtime.

(Fake) example to illustrate my point:

```
<?
$html = run_js_html($input,'myscript.js');
mail('target@email.com','Subject',$html);
?>
```

`$input` contains the input HTML
`myscript.js` contains some JS functionality
`run_js_html` should be a function that runs the script on the html, and then returns the new HTML after javascript.

Is this possible? One way I thought maybe could work is do some kind of HttpRequest through PHP to a PHP file that includes the input HTML and runs the Javascript on it.

Comment: what is "newly generated content"? who generate it?

Comment: can you share link where we can view what you done till now?

Comment: The "newly generated content" should be my old HTML on which some Javascript is run. @nDudani the rest of my script works fine and is a bit too large to share. I don't have current progress because I don't know how I can achieve this. (also the rest of the script is unrelated to the problem)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450233/php-determining-font-size-based-off-of-width) - is this what you're after as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I am aware of PHP's limitations on font resizing and I have a script that does it perfectly. My problem is running that (java)script during PHP runtime. @ whoever downvoted, please comment on why.

Comment: But what does this JavaScript should be doing? You'll have to do the same with PHP as you can't execute JS on static text, just on live DOM elements..

Comment: I know, that's why I'm wondering if it is possible to do an AJAX call to a page that loads in the HTML and Javascript, and then returns the new HTML after running the Javascript (this would add stuff like `style="font-size:x;"`)

Comment: What is the point in all these consecutive HTTP requests? **What data it return you don't have already?**

Comment: I have HTML, this needs to be processed by Javascript to create updated HTML. I need to do this within PHP runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step number 3, if you insist in using jQuery, has to be done on the client side unless you are using server-side JavaScript, which you're not, judging from the PHP tag.

Your options are:

1. Have a client (for example, the person sending the email) execute the JavaScript. You could do this in a hidden iframe if you don't want it to be visible. On the other hand, you might want to make this a feature: Before sending, show the user a preview pane. The submit button could be used to submit the final HTML (after jQuery's manipulation).
2. Install graphical web browser with JavaScript capabilities on the server and capture the output. Probably to much trouble for something like this.
3. Dump jQuery for this purpose and see if you can use PHP's DOMDocument. [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) abstracts a lot away and has a syntax similar to jQuery.

But do you really want to do this? Couldn't you do something like this?

```
function send_some_email()
{
    ob_start();
    include("my_email.php");
    $content = ob_get_clean();
}
// file my_email.php:
<?php 
    $size = 3;
    $length = strlen($title);
    if($length > 50)
        $size = 1;
    elseif($length > 30)
        $size = 2;
?>
<body>
    <?php echo sprintf('<font size="%d">%s</font>', $size, $title); ?>
    <br>
    Hello World.
</body>
```

While judging a string's length by the number of characters is not very reliable, it is an easy implementation. You can also compute the approximate length of the string by:

1. Make or find a function that takes into account letters like 'i' (not wide) and 'M' (wide).
2. Calculate the width of a string with `imagettfbbox()`.

Comment: Server-side Javascript sounds useful, I'm going to look up what that is. The preview-pane might be a good idea, since I'm already using that (it's just not required to be opened right now).

Comment: I am completely aware of the PHP methods to sort of get this functionality, however I'm saving that as a last resort if I can't find a way to get this working. For multiple reasons, 1: the Javascript version is 100% reliable. 2: I might have to run other scripts on other e-mails later on.

Comment: The most-used solution would be Node.Js, but you'd need to learn a 'whole new' way of serverside programming. You'll also need to be able to install new software on the server. What if you calculate the width of the string on the email input screen and save that as an integer into your database?

Comment: Sadly enough that isn't possible, the content is not user submitted but comes from a different database from a separate software package which my client uses and communicates to my database through XML.

Comment: In that case, I'd probably go with calculating the width using `imagettfbbox()`. It's a GD Library function that takes a size, font file (you might need to upload it) and a string and returns the dimensions of the text. Note that the font size is defined in points, so use inline CSS (most mail clients support this): `<span style="font-size:12pt"></span>` Create images with increasingly smaller font sizes until you get something that fits. (`if($resultDimensions[2] < 200) { ... }`)